# Is playing with dolls allowed?

Tags: halal-haram, behavior

My sister's daughter is 5 years old and she likes to play with barbie dolls and I bought her a barbie doll for playing. But my cousin told me that it is not allowed in Islam to play with these type of dolls and keeping these dolls in house will let the angels of rahmath out of home.

What does Islam say about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to `Maalikis`, `Shaafa’is` and `Hanbalis`. These 3 school of thoughts have said that making girls’ toys is not included in the prohibition.

> `Al-Qaadi ‘Iyaad` narrated that most of the scholars said that this is
>   permissible, and he was followed in that by `al-Nawawi` in his
>   commentary on Muslim. He said:
>
> “Exempted from the prohibition on making images that have a shadow are
>   things that are used as toys for girls, because of the exemption that
>   was narrated concerning that. This means that it is permissible,
>   whether they are toys in the shape of people or animals,
>   three-dimensional or otherwise, and whether they are supposed to
>   represent real animals or not, such as a horse with wings…

Majority of scholars use the hadith of Aisha as an evidence for this exemption:

`‘Aa’ishah` (may Allaah be pleased with her) in which she says:

> I used to play with dolls in the house of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him). I had friends who used to play with me. When the Messenger of Allaah (PBUH) came in, they would hide themselves, then he would call them to join me and play with me.

---

In conclusion, Your cousin is wrong according to the hadith, and that angels would not come in the house because of the doll is wrong too.

For More info [click here](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/9473)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your cousin might be referring to [this](http://authentichadithfoundation.org/sahih-bukhari-2105/) hadith. Prophet Muhammad PBUH used the words "these paintings", which means specific type of paintings. It is well-known that idols were used as to worship and they represented a image of an entity that was considered alive. That's why on the day of resurrection, it will be asked to make them alive (as mentioned in the hadith)

Since barbie dolls are not representation of someone who is worshipped as god, it can not be considered something that is "haram".

Answer (score 0):

The barbie is not someone who is worshipped as a God but lots of girls wanted to be like her.. doing plastic surgery to be like barbie.
At the end, they change the creation of Allah because of that dolls.

Comment: This is a nice input, but not an answer as we expect here on SE. Please consider reading http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer!